# Does F_x generates "Transverse Shear Stress" shear stress at the fixed end A?

Tags: stresses, machine-design, shear

Considering the applied forces $F_y=F_y=0$ and $F_x=400$ lbf, what type of stresses does $F_x$ produce? I understand that $F_x$ causes tensile and bending stress but not sure about the transverse shear stress (even though it may be very small).

Based on the definition, the transverse shear stress is always accompanied by bending stress but following the formula $\tau = \frac{VQ}{Ib}$, we realize that $F_x$ doesn't have any shear force ($V=0$). So is the transverse shear stress zero?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right the handle doesn't have any shear.

The only member that has shear is member BC. It has a constant shear in the plane XZ of

$V=400lbs$

Comment: Kamran,

thanks for confirming!